# Is there a way to refresh a wpf page at run-time when a button is pressed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a DataGrid with a list of options. I created a button to swap between French and English (which works fine), but if I press the button while the form with the DataGrid is displayed, the options do not change language. If I exit the page and reopen it, though, the options are displayed in the chosen language. I need a way to simulate this closing and opening, or refreshing of the page in order for this to work. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub btnChangeLanguage_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnChangeLanguage.Click
        Try
            If CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.English Then
                CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.French
                Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("fr-CA")
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
                gCurrentStrLanguage = "FR"
                subLoadReportList()


            ElseIf CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.French Then
                CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.English
                Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-CA")
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
                gCurrentStrLanguage = "EN"
                subLoadReportList()

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub subLoadReportList()
        Try
            If gCurrentStrLanguage Is Nothing OrElse gCurrentStrLanguage = "EN" Then
                dgDefinedReport.ItemsSource = ActiveReports
                dgDefinedReport.DisplayMemberPath = "Name_English"
                dgDefinedReport.SelectedValuePath = "Defined_Report_ID"
            Else
                dgDefinedReport.ItemsSource = ActiveReports
                dgDefinedReport.DisplayMemberPath = "Name_French"
                dgDefinedReport.SelectedValuePath = "Defined_Report_ID"
            End If

            dgDefinedReport.ItemsSource = ActiveReports
            dgDefinedReport.ItemsSource = AllowedReports    ' 26 Aug 2014 DBE - Add security to this screen
            dgDefinedReport.DisplayMemberPath = "Report_Name"
            dgDefinedReport.SelectedValuePath = "Defined_Report_ID"

        Catch ex As Exception
            strError = ex.Message & vbCrLf & " IN: " & Me.GetType.FullName
            Throw New LegalServicesException(ex)
        Finally
            If strError.Length() > 0 Then
                modGlobalFunctions.DisplayErrorMsg(strError, strError)
                strError = String.Empty
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I currently do not have a 'refresh' button. I will need the page to refresh once the btnChangeLanguage is clicked.

Comment: There are ways to do that but is better if you show us your code so we can better understand what you have done and how we can help you.

Comment: You will need to show the code in the refresh button. Edit your question.

Comment: I've added what I have currently

Comment: Maybe it's just a cut & paste error but your code for subLoadReportList() does not look right. You set it to the appropriate data for the current language but then override it all to use AllowedReports & "Report_Name" instead.